# Numpy reshape image data into batches

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I'm having a Numpy shape issue. I have a batch of 128x128x3 images and I am trying to reshape my list to be of shape batch_size x 128 x 128 x 3.

Let's walk through what I have so far.

We have a batch of 3 lists that include the image and some other meta data. Visually:

```
my_data

|row|raw_image|meta_data1|meta_data2| 
-------------------------------------
|1  |128x128x3|8685      |'here'    |
-------------------------------------
|2  |128x128x3|8402      |'there'   |
-------------------------------------
|3  |128x128x3|5498      |'where'   |

print(my_data.shape) #(3,4)
```

We only want to grab the raw_image data:

```
image_data = my_data[:, 1]
print(image_data.shape) #(3,)
print(image_data[0].shape) #(128,128,3)
```

I would think that image_data would already be in 3x128x128x3, however I am getting errors, such as:

> ValueError: Error when checking: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (384, 128, 3)

or

> ValueError: Error when checking: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 1)

I've tried reshaping, like so:

```
np.reshape(image_data, (3, 128, 128, 3))
```

But get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (3,128,128,3)

So, how should I proceed? I've tried combinations with vstack, reshape, extend dim, removing a dim...

Comment: If it makes any difference, the desire is to feed this into a Keras CNN. The goal is to send the whole batch into the model in one predict call.

Comment: What code is issuing the first 2 `ValueError`?  What's the `shape` and `dtype` of `my_data`?  The description `batch of 3 lists` is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `image_data` is an array of objects, you can merge them using `np.stack(image_data)`; This should stack all images inside `image_data` by the first axis and create the 4d array as you need.

Comment: concat, hstack, vstack - tried them, not quite the result. vstack returns shape (384, 128, 3)

Comment: Yep. It should be `np.stack` actually, edited the answer.